# How to Inference With Keras Sequential Models (Text Classification)

Tags: python, keras, nlp, tensorflow, lstm

**I have the following LSTM model and I can't make inference with it:**

```
print("Define LSTM model")

rnnmodel=Sequential()
rnnmodel.add(embedding_layer)

rnnmodel.add(LSTM(128, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
rnnmodel.add(Dense(2, activation="sigmoid"))

rnnmodel.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
                 optimizer="adam",
                 metrics=["accuracy"])

rnnmodel.fit(X_train, y_train,
             batch_size=256,
             epochs=1,
             validation_data=(x_val, y_val))

score, acc=rnnmodel.evaluate(test_data, test_labels, batch_size=128)
print(f"Test accuracy with RNN: {acc}")
```

(epoch is 1 to test) I want to make an inference with the text, let's say

```
text=["the product was horrible"]
```

I check the documentation of [tf.keras.Sequential](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential#predict) and it states I should use the `predict` function and the input should be *"A Numpy array (or array-like), or a list of arrays (in case the model has multiple inputs)."*

**So what I did is:**

```
text=["the product was horrible"]
inference_sequence=tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(text)
inference_data=pad_sequences(inference_sequence, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)

predictions=rnnmodel.predict(inference_data)

print(predictions)
```

and it gives me the result `[[0.63219154 0.33410403]]`

**However I've given only one sentence. Why it gives me two results? I checked the `sigmoid` documentation from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/activations/sigmoid) and for an confirmed it should return only one result. So what's the problem here?**

**I also tried other approaches to make inference like mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61443543/how-to-make-prediction-on-keras-text-classification**

**So I did:**

```
text=["the product was horrible"]
rnnmodel.predict(text)
```

and it gives me the warning: *WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 1000) for input Tensor("embedding_input:0", shape=(None, 1000), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 1).* **and stuck forever.**

What should I do I just can't make an inference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I checked the sigmoid documentation from here and for a confirmed it should return only one result. So what's the problem here?*

You have used 2 Neurons at the output layer. So, each is responsible for one output.

**Either**, *change the neuron count to 1 and y_true to the 1-D array*.

**Or** *change the activation function to Softmax*.

```
text=["the product was horrible"]
rnnmodel.predict(text)
```

This will not work.

*The embedding layer expects Label encoded data. So the first approach is correct.*

Comment: yep you're correct. Switched to softmax working now. Thank you.